# In ASP.net MVC, why the controller can be moved outside of the Controllers folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-5.2

By mistake, I have created my HomeController.cs in the folder Models.
This is the only controller of my webapplication. The view path is: Views/Home/Index.cshtml

When I run the application, there is no problem, it can find the controller.
I tried also to move it to a subfolder like Views/Home/HomeController.cs
and still no problem.

I can't find a route or config which will tell the application where the controller is so I wonder how it works ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MVC looks for anything that inherits from `Controller` when trying to match a route to a controller, it really doesn't matter where the controller resides or what namespace the controller is in.

For a fun little experiment, this will generate the error "Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'..." because you have two controllers with the same name in different namespaces, and MVC doesn't know which one to use.

```
namespace Something
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()...
    }  
}

namespace OrOther
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()...
    }  
}
```

Comment: As an added question, how would you force a load order of a controller named the same in a different namespace, whereby the 2nd "HomeController" will be loaded instead? Example, Areas or Multi-Tenancy?